# ivy inline resolve using version matcher / status

Tags: ivy

I am interested in knowing how to do "inline" resolve using version matcher.

Problem Statement: 
I have artifacts from two releases being published in the shared repo. Rel 1 has revisions of the order - 1.1, 1.2 and so on and Rel 2 has revisions of the order - 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 ans so on.

I need to create an ear with the latest wars from the different releases (Rel 1, Rel 2 and so on). For this I am trying to inline resolve the different wars by iterating through the following snippet:

```
            <ivy:resolve  organisation="com.barclays.eps" module="scp-eps-cards" 
                changing="true" revision="latest.LIVE-build-rel-@{i}" inline="true" transitive="false" keep="true" refresh="true" type="war"/>


            <ivy:retrieve pattern="target/ear/[artifact]-[revision]-@{i}.[ext]" 
                organisation="com.barclays.eps" module="scp-eps-cards" revision="latest.LIVE-build-rel-@{i}" inline="true" transitive="false" type="war" />
            <ivy:retrieve ivypattern="target/ear/[artifact]-[revision]-2.[ext]" 
                organisation="com.barclays.eps" module="scp-eps-cards" revision="latest.LIVE-build-rel-@{i}" inline="true" transitive="false" type="xml" />
```

the statuses have been set in the ivy-settings.xml file in the following order:

```
    <statuses default="dev-build-rel-2">
    <status name="LIVE-build-rel-2" integration="true"/>
    <status name="daily-build-rel-2" integration="true"/>
    <status name="dev-build-rel-2" integration="true"/>
    <status name="dev-build-rel-1" integration="true"/>
    <status name="release" integration="false"/>
    <status name="integration" integration="true"/>
</statuses>
```

However when I am trying to resolve I am only getting the artifacts with status="LIVE-build-rel-2" due to the order in which it has been mentioned.

I am wondering if this can be achieved by using version matcher while performing the inline resolve. I have tried using the same, but getting the error: cannot find foo(2)

Can any one please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Solution provided here by tmcglynn :
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596002/is-there-a-way-to-specify-an-ivy-dependency-using-a-dynamic-revision-but-restric?rq=1)

is somewhat related to what I am thinking. However, the solution here works for a single branch. where as if I wish to use branch it would be 1 for Rel-1 and 2 for Rel-2 in which case the resolve fails. :(